# W3CEPRJaxbBinding_jaxb22.xml; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 162; Unexpected <bindings> appears at line 20 column 162

Tags: spring-boot, maven, wsdl, cxf-codegen-plugin, java-17

I am trying to update my maven SpringBoot application with the latest Java 17 and every dependency to the latest version.

**cxf-codegen-plugin** started to throw interesting exception which I don't really understand, and cannot find any proper solution to solve it:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.12:wsdl2java (generate-endpoint-sources) on project autorefundexporter: 
Exit code: 1
Command line was: cmd.exe /X /C "C:\apps\Java\x64\jdk-17\bin\java.exe --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED -jar C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-18084792511058340769\cxf-codegen2773993495141282809.jar C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-18084792511058340769\cxf-w2j12014482162652070777args"


    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
Exit code: 1
Command line was: cmd.exe /X /C "C:\apps\Java\x64\jdk-17\bin\java.exe --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED -jar C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-18084792511058340769\cxf-codegen2773993495141282809.jar C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-18084792511058340769\cxf-w2j12014482162652070777args"


    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.runForked (AbstractCodegenMoho.java:694)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.forkOnce (AbstractCodegenMoho.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute (AbstractCodegenMoho.java:268)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute (WSDL2JavaMojo.java:501)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Maven warning shows something else also:

```
[WARNING] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-common/3.3.12/cxf-tools-common-3.3.12.jar!/org/apache/cxf/tools/common/jaxb/W3CEPRJaxbBinding_jaxb22.xml; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 162; Unexpected <bindings> appears at line 20 column 162
```

Within these warnings:

```
[WARNING] Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-common/3.3.12/cxf-tools-common-3.3.12.jar!/org/apache/cxf/tools/common/jaxb/W3CEPRJaxbBinding_jaxb22.xml [20,162]: Unexpected <bindings> appears at line 20 column 162
[WARNING] 
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolErrorListener.throwToolException(ToolErrorListener.java:87)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:158)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:404)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.ForkOnceWSDL2Java.main(ForkOnceWSDL2Java.java:51)
[WARNING] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-common/3.3.12/cxf-tools-common-3.3.12.jar!/org/apache/cxf/tools/common/jaxb/W3CEPRJaxbBinding_jaxb22.xml; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 162; Unexpected <bindings> appears at line 20 column 162
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.unexpectedX(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:607)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.unexpectedEnterElement(NGCCHandler.java:165)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.Schema.enterElement(Schema.java:376)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.startElement(NGCCRuntime.java:233)
[WARNING]   at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:539)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.util.SubtreeCutter.startElement(SubtreeCutter.java:78)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.startElement(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:120)
[WARNING]   at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:539)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.startElement(IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.java:98)
[WARNING]   at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:539)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.CustomizationContextChecker.startElement(CustomizationContextChecker.java:163)
[WARNING]   at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:539)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner$LocationResolver.startElement(DOMForestScanner.java:117)
[WARNING]   at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:214)
[WARNING]   at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:97)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:62)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:70)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestParser.parse(DOMForestParser.java:74)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:210)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:351)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:98)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:141)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:130)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:475)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:240)
[WARNING]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:67)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:445)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:715)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:259)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:156)
[WARNING]   ... 5 more
```

This is how my plugin is configured:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-endpoint-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/my.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>com.my.app.generated
                            </extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                        <validate>none</validate>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

No idea what to do now.. Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I added dependencies to the plugin. After removing all dependencies, everything worked perfectly:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-endpoint-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/my.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>com.my.app.generated
                            </extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                        <validate>none</validate>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me a lot of time. I had a gradle build with similar issue. I had to remove the following dependencies:

wsdl2java('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
    wsdl2java('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0')
    wsdl2java('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0')
    wsdl2java('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.3.0') */